# need to get the exact redirect link

Tags: python-2.7, mechanize, data-cleaning

I need to get the final url of the link. But this code is only giving me a link to its store

It is returning me the link: http://www.amazon.in/electronics/b?ie=UTF8&node=976419031

But what I need is: http://www.amazon.in/Samsung-G-550FY-On5-Pro-Gold/dp/B01FM7GGFI?tag=prdeskdetailmob-21&ascsubtag=desktop-mobile-15920-blank-27092016

```
import mechanize

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.open("https://priceraja.com/r/go2store.php?mpc=mobile--1178916--15920--deskdetail")
br.select_form(nr=0)
br.submit()
x=br.geturl()
print x
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from selenium import webdriver
chrome_path = r"C:\Users\Bhanwar\Desktop\price raja mobile\working\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
link = "https://priceraja.com/r/go2store.php?mpc=mobile--1185105--15236--deskdetail"
driver.get(link)
while(link == driver.current_url):
  time.sleep(3)
redirected_url = driver.current_url
print redirected_url
```